# Strange results returned from String.slice() method

Tags: javascript, string, slice

My case is to separate a string into array of strings and then convert every three characters into a string. ( e.g. "xxxyyy" -> `['xxx','yyy']` )

```js
const translate = function (RNA) {
    var arrRna = Array.from(RNA);
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in arrRna) {
        if ((key % 3) == 0) {
            var temp = RNA.slice( key,  (key+3));
            arr.push(temp);
        }

    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

Expected result : `['xxx','yyy','zzz']`

But the result that I want is : `[ 'xxx', 'yyyzzz', 'zzz' ]`

Also, I noticed that the slice method works as expected in first iteration but after that, the weird result --> 'yyyzzz'. Why??

Comment: You shouldn't use `for...in` loops on arrays, that's generally unreliable given the (unfortunately) common practice of adding enumerable methods to built-in types (and the fact that the keys are strings instead of numbers as pointed out in the answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tada!  Rather than converting the string to an array and going through each character waiting for the index to be a multiple of 3, simply count by 3s.

```js
function translate(rna) {
  let arr = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < rna.length; i += 3) {
    arr.push(rna.slice(i, i + 3));
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(translate('xxxydyyzzzd'));
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that `for..in` loops over *property names*, and property names are always *strings*. So, for example, when `key` is 3:

```
var temp = RNA.slice( key,  (key+3));
```

evaluates to

```
var temp = RNA.slice('3',  '33');
```

because `+` *concatenates* when strings are involved. You might cast to `Number` first:

```js
const translate = function(RNA) {
  var arrRna = Array.from(RNA);
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in arrRna) {
    key = Number(key);
    if ((key % 3) == 0) {
      var temp = RNA.slice(key, (key + 3));
      arr.push(temp);
    }

  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

Or, you might chunk the array using a plain `for` loop, whose logic might be easier to understand at a glance:

```js
const translate = function(RNA) {
  const output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < RNA.length; i += 3) {
    output.push(RNA.slice(i, i + 3));
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

Another option would be to use a global regular expression `.match`:

```js
const translate = RNA => RNA.match(/.{1,3}/g);
console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

Comment: you are god like, the regex solution is interesting

Answer (score 1):

Approach using `Array.from()` with mapping callback to do whole process

```js
const translate = (RNA) => {
  return Array.from({length: Math.ceil(RNA.length/3)}, (_,i)=> RNA.slice(i*3, i*3+3));       
}

console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I figured out the problem. When you add 3 to the key, it concatenantes the result to give you 0, 03, 3, 33, 6, 63 as key and key+3 giving you the result you see.

```js
const translate = function (RNA) {
    var arrRna = Array.from(RNA);
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in arrRna) {
        if ((key % 3) == 0) {
            console.log(key)
            console.log(key+3)
            var temp = RNA.slice( key,  (key+3));
            arr.push(temp);
        }

    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

The solution is simple. Add a '+' before key. This type casts it to numeric giving you the expected result.

```js
const translate = function (RNA) {
    var arrRna = Array.from(RNA);
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in arrRna) {
        if ((key % 3) == 0) {
            var temp = RNA.slice( +key,  (+key+3));
            arr.push(temp);
        }

    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(translate('xxxyyyzzz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the adding a number to a string, which keys of objects are, you could take a generator for an arbitrary slicing of strings.

```js
function* translate (string, size) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < string.length) yield string.slice(i, i += size);
}

console.log([...translate('xxxyyyzzz', 3)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing one more solution independent of no of characters(3)

```
let spltStr = myStr =>
  [...myStr.toLowerCase()].reduce((acc, char) => {
    let last = acc[acc.length - 1];
    !last || last[last.length - 1] !== char
      ? acc.push(char)
      : (acc[acc.length - 1] += char);
    return acc;
  }, []);
```